# sans serif math in toc/lof/lot with tocloft package

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

How do I get sans serif fonts for captions containing math characters in lists?

Here is a mwe where the x^2 from mathmode in the list of figures is represented with serifs instead of the wanted sans serif font:

```
\documentclass[]{article}   
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering Figure\caption{test x\textsuperscript{2}}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering Figure\caption{test $x^2$}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with the package [`sansmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sansmath) which provides two commands `\sansmath` and `unsansmath`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}   
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\sansmath
\listoffigures
\unsansmath

\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering Figure\caption{test x\textsuperscript{2}}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering Figure\caption{test $x+x^2$}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]